# Alternative to Complex.h in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I know very little about VS, and was surprised when my linux code did not compile on windows. The problem seams from the lack of `<complex.h>` in VS. My question is this: do people re-implement  in their Windows applications, or is there a public domain version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

since C++ is not an option, and neither is GCC, can't you just... Download the header, and include it into your project yourself: `#include"complex.h"`? You could download a minimal version of MinGW and just copy the header file over.

Comment: He will also need the libraries.

Comment: can't he just copy those too?

Comment: this answer is wrong: you cannot just use complex.h to get complex support.

If you can't use gcc and can't use C++, the only solution is to drop support for C99 complex.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure when I posted this answer, it was just a thought that I didn't see elsewhere. Can you be specific as to why it can't be done? Or edit the answer?

Comment: @CarsonMyers C99 complex _requires_ compiler support.

Answer (score 2):

`<complex.h>` is a new feature of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and Visual Studio (at least up to 2008) only supports ISO/IEC 9899:1990 with some extensions, so `complex.h` isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of using C++ instead of C, you can use the `complex` header. Visual C++ supports C89, but not C99, where `complex.h` is defined.

If C++ is not an option, you can either use another compiler (there are Windows ports of GCC available, for example), or try to find a third-party implementation.

Comment: c++ is not an option, and neither is compiling via gcc